# How to query a persisted dataframe in spark job (A) from another spark job (B)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

[image: diagram]There are two spark streaming jobs running on different containers - let's call them teacher job and student job. Both are reading from two different kafka topics. When a student message comes into the student spark job, I need to 'query' the teacher job's persisted data to retrieve the teacher associated with that student (in this example, the student only has one teacher but a teacher can have many students). How can I persist a key value pair(or a teacher data frame) in the teacher job and then retrieve/lookup that teacher in the student job so I can process that student knowing it's teacher? Can I use persist() in one job and unpersist() in another?

Comment: Hard to follow your prose. What is streaming, what is static? The relationship stu - tch where is that coming from, for the stream or static? Try and reorganize the question with an example, the prose vs titie are not in sync imho.

Comment: Student messages and Teacher messages are streaming in. The student job gets student messages streamed in real time and the teacher job gets messages streamed in real time but are asynchronus from each other. The teacher message has one student listed in its payload. The student payload doesn't have it's teacher listed in its payload. I need to get the teacher for that student - within the context of the student spark streaming job.

Comment: Interesting concept that I seem not to follow. How do explain the persisted dataframe. You can have stream stream joins. https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/stream-stream-joins-scala.html Would that not be more advisable?

Comment: I will look into that. We have most of this architecture up and running and i've been tasked with the concept of associating the student and teacher together in the student job. I'm fairly new to spark and didn't know what my options were what it comes to getting data from another spark job. I'd rather not have to stand up an intermediate database just for that lookup if spark has a mechanism to easily do what I need. I added a diagram to maybe help with the clarification.

Comment: Spark Kafka Integration with Structured Streaming

Comment: awesome, ty. So let me see if I have this straight. I will set up 2 kafka sink streams in my 'student' job, one from the student kafka topic and one from the teacher kafka topic. From there can I replay my teacher kafka topic from the beginning each time the student spark job receives a new student message (because the teacher message has already came in possibly hours ago)? If so then use filter to select from the teacher topic record that matches the current student record that is currently being processed in the student spark job?

Comment: As the manual states I believe.

Comment: how will this work @thebluephantom? Kafka is not a storage but a message broker. How you will be able to query a teacher that arrived 3 hours before his students data? You will need to keep the data into memory for 3 hours! If you do you violate the default functionality of Spark by using its cache as memory storage!

Comment: There are windows that you specify if memory serves correct. I take your point but base the approach on the question.

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis  So if you look in the manual you are well aware of stream stream join and stream static join. If you look at the threads, you will note I have some hesitancy here, but base things on the question / use case asked. I am sure that the questioner will use stream static if this is better and having been pointed to the relevant source.

Comment: in the (example)[https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/stream-stream-joins-scala.html] that you mentioned the watermark should relatively be low and not a couple of hours. In the above case @EbbnFlow mentioned that the data between teachers and students might get retrieved with 2-3 hours difference. In this case spark should keep the data 2-3 backward (via watermarking) which is too long in my opinion and does not fit with streaming principles for a continuous processing.

Comment: but the volume of data may well be low ... can you see millions of teachers. Yes your answer is also applicable but the the Hbase technique is a given for large numbers - of say customers. IGNITE ok, oddly enough I am about to install that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the evidence it appears that Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka Integration utilizing Stream - Stream Join is the way to go.